# Shifting pages within website

Tags: grid, containers, shift, fluid

I have just about finished adding all of the content to each page of my website. I've noticed, however, when I navigate between links some of the pages shift to the right about 10 px or so. This is *extremely* irritating. All of my pages are contained within the same container using a fluid grid. However, not all pages have the same amount of content. I noticed that pages with empty divs don't shift when I navigate between them. However, if I navigate from a page with content to a page with little or no content, I see the shift. Should this be happening if all of my pages are using the same container, same fluid grid? Does this make sense? Can you sense my desperation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at your browser vertical scroll? This is probably your desperation ;-)